# Validation across fields in react-redux-form

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux-form

I've created [this](https://codepen.io/im1dermike/pen/BJNQEe) example of the issue I'm facing.  Here is the code for the form:

```
  <Form model="user" onSubmit={v => console.log(v)}>
    <div className="field">
      <Control.text 
        model=".items[0]" 
        validators={{
          exists: (value) => !exists(value, 0, user.items)
        }} />
      <Errors
        className="errors"
        model=".items[0]" 
        show="touched"
        messages={{
          exists: "Item already exists"
        }} />
    </div>
    <div className="field">
      <Control.text 
        model=".items[1]" 
        validators={{
          exists: (value) => !exists(value, 1, user.items)
        }} />
      <Errors
        className="errors"
        model=".items[1]" 
        show="touched"
        messages={{
          exists: "Item already exists"
        }} />
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </Form>


function exists(value, index, list) {
  if (!value) {
    return false;
  }
  const existingValue = list.find((item, i) => {
    return i !== index && item === value;
  });
  return !!existingValue;
}
```

I'm trying to create a validator which will ensure unique items in a list.  Each item in the list has its own `input` control.  The expected behavior IMO is for the error message to be displayed for any textbox the moment their values are not unique across the list.  I believe this would require validation to fire for *all* fields in the list when *any* field changes.

The way it is now, if the same value is entered, an error is displayed for only that control.  To get the error to be displayed for a different control that contains a duplicate value, you would need to switch to that control and update the value to match the existing value.  Even more problematic, if both controls in the example have the same value and both errors are displaying, if you change one of the values, the error message will still display for the other control.

What is the best way to "link" validation together across controls for an example like this?

Answer (score 0):

I ultimately ended up using RRF's form-level validators to solve the issue.  It's not perfect, because you can't identify the specific array items that are in error, but it works.

```
export function getValidators() {
  return {
    '': {
      uniqueCodes: (values) => {
        const items = filter(values.items, item => {
            return !!item;
        });
        return (new Set(items)).size !== items.length;
      }
    }
  };
}

<Form model={formModel} onSubmit={() => this.onSave()} validators={getValidators()}>
  ...
</Form
```